# How does tank size relate to output velocity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, gas

I'm comparing air compressors, and I don't understand why there isn't a correlation between tank size+max pressure and SCFM.  Here are a few examples of some models:

| Model | Tank (gallons) | SCFM @ 90 PSI | Max PSI | Moles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.2 | 120 | 1.28496 |
| B | 1 | 0.8 | 135 | 1.44558 |
| C | 2 | 2.0 | 135 | 2.89116 |
| D | 3 | 0.6 | 100 | 3.21240 |

<sub>Moles are calculated using ideal gas law `pV = nRT` at 68°F</sub>

To me, there should be a strong correlation between tank size and the amount of time that the tank can supply a given pressure.  While model D doesn't hold air at quite as high of pressure as the other three models, it holds a larger volume.  Models B and C hold air at the same pressure, with C having a tank twice as large the moles are exactly double, but the SCFM is 2.5 times as much.

The question I'm trying to answer is: for a given model, if the output is regulated to 90 PSI, how long would I be able to continuously draw air without the output pressure falling below 90 PSI?  I don't actually need a duration, I just want to be able to compare models against each other.  I thought this is what the manufacturer-supplied SCFM number is, so there's something I'm not understanding.

I should note that models A, B, and C are representative for "quiet" compressors, and the D model costs less than half of models A and B and is signiticantly noiser.

Comment: SCFM is a function of compressor design, not tank volume.

Comment: SCFM is the measurement of the output of the tank, not the input.  The compressor need not be running for air to rush out of the tank

Comment: Due to the continuity equation, on average, the tank can't output more than is input to it by the compressor.

Comment: @DavidWhite : actually, the tank can "output more than is input to it by the compressor" for a limited time.

Comment: @akhmeteli, the point that I am trying to make is this: the quoted SCFM @ 90 psi assumes continuous running at 90 psi.  That flow rate is dependent on the compressor, not the tank size.  Sure, if you pump the indicated tanks up to the max pressure, you can get more than the specified flow rate, but you will pull the tank pressure down to 90 psi.  At that point, the compressor can only supply the indicated SCFM if you are to remain at 90 psi.

Answer (score 1):

SCFM is standard cubic foot **per** minute, so it has little to do with the tank size.

EDIT (Dec 7, 2021): The air receiver tank size determines how much time you can use your air-powered equipment without interruptions when the air demand exceeds the compressor output (in SCFM). A compressor can work without any air receiver tank if its output is sufficient for the demand. So the tank size does not necessarily depend on the output (SCFM). See, e.g., https://www.vmacair.com/blog/sizing-air-receiver-tank/ for details, including tank sizing formulas.

Comment: The question isn't about tank size but substance

Comment: @user321248 :  I don't understand your comment but see my EDIT.